# Is it possible to track a mobile phone (cell phone) without Internet/GPS?

Tags: internet, user, mobile-phone, tracking

Is it possible to track the current location of a
Mobile user without using internet and GPS? Is
there any way of locating the user by
only using the network provider info, signal
reception and transmission distance from the
nearest mobile operator antenna?
Is there any computer software that can be used to track the location of the mobile user?

Comment: actually this question is flagged off from stack overflow to here, if this question doesn't fit to be here,suggest where could i post this. it would be helpful.

Comment: i will make the question a little more clear. consider two persons who own 2 non-gprs/gps cell phones and one wants to get the location of the other. since both have non-gprs/gps phones their only way to find the location is with the help of mobile number and network operator. so is this possible to find the location with the help of these two or you have a better way to find the location apart from gps/gprs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes there is. The mobile provider needs to know where your phone (or rather, near which transmission tower your phone is) so they can send incoming phone calls to you. No internet is needed.

2) Nobody can track anything using GPS. GPS is **receive only**.

3) Please read or <strike>FAQ</strike> helpcenter to see what is on-topic and off-topic. You can find it at the top of the webpage, slightly to the right end.

---

To clarify GPS:

Imagine a person standing on a hill top shouting: 'I am on the hill top and the time is *precisely* 15:00 hours and 0 seconds'.  If you hear that message at 15:00 hours and 3 seconds then you know you are 1km away from that hill top. (sound travels at about 1km per 3 seconds).

Replace the person shouting with a few satellites which broadcast a time signal (broadcast/shout only) and you get GPS.

Since you do not talk/shout/send anything back to the person on the hill there is no way for them to track you.

Comment: I think the poster was asking for a tutorial on *how* to track them. This is interesting either way though.

Comment: Ah. Given the close vote (not mine) the OP may need to more clearly formulate the question.

Comment: thanks hennes, i will make the question a little more clear. consider two persons who own 2 non-gprs/gps cell phones and one wants to get the location of the other. since both have non-gprs/gps phones their only way to find the location is with the help of mobile number and network operator.  so is this possible to find the location with the help of these two or you have a better way to find the location apart from gps/gprs?